# Trial solution for modulational instability

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-dynamics

I have a simple linear differential equation of the following form:

$\frac{\partial a}{\partial z} + i\beta_2\frac{\partial^2 a}{\partial t^2} = i\gamma P(a+a^*)$

I seek the solution to $a(z,t)$, and $a^*$ is the complex conjugate. $\beta_2$, $\gamma$ and $P$ are all constants, and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Apparently, the following trial solution is valid:

$a = c_1\exp[i(kz-\omega t)] + c_1^*\exp[-i(kz-\omega t)]$

if the following dispersion relation is satisfied:

$k = \pm \sqrt{\beta_2^2\omega^4 + 2\gamma P\beta_2\omega^2}$

However, I am unable to validate this. When I plug the trial solution into the differential equation, there is no way that a $k^2$ pops out, which would eventually let me get a dispersion relation of the form shown (in a square root).

This problem is related to modulation instabilities (MI) in nonlinear optical systems. The wiki page [on MI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulational_instability) makes the claim that this solution is valid, but does not provide a proof, and the book referenced by that page does the same thing, without proof. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show some steps? You should get a $k$ term from the first derivative and a $\omega^2$ term from the second derivative. At some point you might need to square the equation/multiply by some conjugate, giving the overall form of $k^2 + \gamma^2P^2 = (\beta_2\omega^2+\gamma P)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

[Substiuting trial solution in the differential equation. Compare +ve and -ve exponential part. I got 2 equation(1 & 2), multiply them and find k^2. To match with dispersion relation, subtract these two equations. After that, you can figure out by yourself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zbbW.jpg)

Comment: Click on above link to see all steps of the solution in an attached picture.